# How to set the backcolor of a label in a separate form C#

Tags: c#, forms, backcolor

I have the code

```
            Results toResults = new Results();
            correct = 0;
            incorrect = 0;
            //Indicates clearly which answers are correct
            if (userGuessArray[0]==decompTimeArray[0])
            {
                toResults.yourAnswerLabel1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                lblone.BackColor = Color.Green;
                correct++;
            }
            else
            {
                toResults.yourAnswerLabel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                lblone.BackColor = Color.Red;
                incorrect++;
            }
```

It doesn't seem to work for setting the backcolor of the label on the second form. I made it set the color on itself and that works but it just won't go to the other form. How might I remedy this?

I have indeed searched for many solutions to this but haven't found any.

Here is the code that actually shows it.

```
private void ShowResults()
        {
            //Shows the Results form.
            toResults.Show();
        }



private void resultsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           ShowResults();

        }
```

Comment: We don't really know what you mean by "your second form". Perhaps the second form hasn't finished initialising yet?

Comment: Because you are creating a NEW instance of the form Results. This instance is never shown and you can't see its labels. If you call toResults.Show() you will see the effects of your changes. But I bet that this is not what you are expecting to happen here, right? You should apply these changes to the instance of the Results form already displayed

Comment: You say *this form* and *that other form* but I don't see any in your code. What are you talking about? can you post more code and explain what is going on here?

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize anyone would want to see me making the form pop up. to Pid, would I want to show the form then do any changes that occur?

Answer (score 1):

In your second form create a property that will set those values for you.

Second form:

```
public Color _labelBackColor
{
  get { return myLabel.BackColor; }
  set { myLabel.BackColor = value; }
}
```

You can then change the value by calling

```
toResults._labelBackColor = Color.Green;
```

or by setting it when you instantiate the second form

```
var toResults = new Results { _labelBackColor = Color.Green };
```

Comment: I changed what I did based on what someone else said and it worked. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Windows form application use Static variable.

Create static variable in your main form and keep that to manage your color for the form.

Always read color from that static variable to apply where you want.